# Monitor never detects input, turns off within a few seconds - Samsung LCD lu28e590ds

Tags: display, hardware-failure, external-display, displayport, capacitor

My monitor has caused me troubles before, whenever I unplug&replug the input cable, it could take ~1 hour to detect the input. In the past I ensured not to unplug it, so over nearly a year it didn't cause me any trouble.

Then today I built a new PC and plugged my monitors into it, now one of them will not work. **However I tested using my old PC, the issue is the 100% the monitor**

### Troubleshooting / info:

I tried a working HDMI cable into a working PC. I have 2 identical monitors, so I even tried the working power cable, still nothing.

If I select a source that has no input, 'Check Signal Cable' shows forever, which is expected and means it's probably not a power issue

When the correct source is selected, The monitor goes black for about 3 seconds, before turning off. It never shows any input

All of the settings on the monitor are grayed out, except `System/PC/AV Mode` and `System/Display Port Ver.`. This means the input is not being detected. Testing using my working monitor, those options become available when a source is plugged in. If I keep the settings menu open, the monitor does not shut off. However Input is never being detected.

I've read online that this issue can be caused by bulging capacitors, however I took the monitor apart and I don't see any capacitors at all (unless they are onboard capacitors?) Image of the monitor's boards:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1RL5.jpg

Comment: Okay I tried the monitors with my laptop and the monitor works instantly. I'm going to do more debugging tomorrow evening

Comment: I suggest you reorganize the info you are showing, to show more clearly how many PCs and monitors you have, and which connections work/worked and which don't/didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested both monitors on another machine and both ended up working.

It turns out the HDMI cable was at fault. I'm not sure why my previous test using a known working HDMI cable did not work, but regardless **both monitors are now working in the new system.**